# Putting Images in html Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I do not/ would like to know how to hide images in the html while only putting them in the canvas via javascript. What I am doing now is:

in the body then:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var img = document.getElementById("cerealBox");
                ctx.drawImage(img,400,200)

            </script>
```

I am attempting to just put the image in the canvas but haven't found a way how, I was just learning from W3Schools.

Comment: In general w3schools can be a bit outdated or incomplete (but a good source fot newbies). Anyway a simple search could have give the answer if you look out of w3schoold... About canvas this is a good article: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Comment: If you are trying to hide the images in HTML, then you could simply add a CSS rule like `#cerealBox{display:none;}`

Comment: Thanks derek, that was the most simple fix there was.

Comment: Is there a more reusable solution than the ones posted?

Comment: expiredninja , I believe Dereks was the best probably its much easier, what i ended up doing was using jquery's .hide function to hide the img off the side of my canvas a ways.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFFR6/) .

```
var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081209142622/fantendo/images/e/e6/Super_8_Bit_Mario.png";

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 50, 800, 600, 50, 50, 100, 60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
#gameCanvas { 
    border: 1px solid white; 
    width: 400px; 
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/cerealBox.png';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 400, 200);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <img id="myImage" src=""></img>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var imgEl = document.getElementById("myImage");
 imgEl.setAttribute("src", "/Images/MyImages/Album1/myPic.jpg");
```